# My subquery is not correctly providing an accurate subtotal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a subquery that will generate a new column showing Total Paid Hours by Department Number.  The Paid Hours field is a varchar data type and contains some blanks.  So I am converting the data from varchar to Decimal and replacing any nulls with a 0 prior to summing.  The issue I am having is that for most instances, my subquery is doubling my totals.  Any idea what I may be doing wrong?  This is my first posting on this site....so if I am posting in the wrong area or more clarification is needed please let me know.  Thanks!

The provided picture shows my issue.  The "Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department" field should show 11,822 Total Paid Hours....instead it is doubling the number(s) and showing 23,644.  4.5 + 2741.5 + 7828 + 1248 = 11,822.

[This is the Data I am working with.  Note Paid Hours at the far right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PML06.png)

[Below are my current results when I try to sum the Paid Hours by Department No.  My Total Hours are doubling.  Should be 11822.00 and not 23644.00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5cZ3.png)

```
select distinct 
 [Department_No] 
,[Department_Description]
,[JOB_CODE]
,[JOB_CODE_DESC]
,[Paid Hours]
,(Select sum(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), ISNULL(NULLIF([Paid Hours], ''), '0'))) 
  from [STD].[Payroll] t1a 
  where t1a.[Department_No] = PAL.[Department_No]
 ) as Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department
from [STD].[Payroll] PAL
```

Comment: Please set an image description.

Comment: What is your expected result from this ?

Comment: Added imaged description.  The result in the above example should show 11,822 for the "Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department".  4.5 + 2741.5 + 7828 + 1248 = 11,822.  Instead the result is doubling my numbers and showing 23,644.  .

Comment: Learn to debug your code. Usually the use of DISTINCT is a big red flag that something is logically wrong with the query or covers up a schema flaw. So remove it from the outer query and just temporarily comment out the total sum and throw in an order by clause to help read the resultset. What rows are returned (e.g., for code 10)?

Comment: Thanks- I removed Distinct.  I threw Distinct into the code late last night to see if the results changed.  Received same result with and without Distinct in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM()` with window function

```
select 
    [Department_No] 
   ,[Department_Description]
   ,[JOB_CODE]
   ,[JOB_CODE_DESC]
   ,[Paid Hours]
   SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), ISNULL(NULLIF([Paid Hours], ''), '0'))) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY [Department_No]) AS Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department
from [STD].[Payroll] PAL
```

Comment: Thanks squirrel!  I tested your code but unfortunately my numbers are still doubling.  4.5 + 2741.5 + 7828 + 1248 = 11,822.  However my total is still showing 23,644.  Any thoughts

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result. Without that, we can't really help. The query does what it is supposed to do. It is probably your data

Comment: Hi Squirrel- I did add an image of the results at the very top of the feed.  Please let me know if it is not visible for some reason.

Comment: the image does not helps at all as that is the result of your current query. We want to see the a sample of raw data from the `Payroll` and based on that sample, what is the expected result

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using `select distinct`, so I'm removing it.

Use window functions and `try_convert()`:

```
select Department_No, Department_Description,
       JOB_CODE, JOB_CODE_DESC, [Paid Hours],
       SUM(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), [Paid Hours])) OVER (PARTITION BY Department_No) as Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department
from [STD].[Payroll] PAL;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  Unfortunately my Total Paid Hours are still doubling.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Frank . . . That would suggest duplicates in the data.

Comment: I was told I would have a unique data set.  Worked the data assuming there were no duplicates. Based on your comment, I went back and reviewed the data. Found a "Version" column at the end of the dataset, which I did not include in the screen shots. For whatever reason, some employees have different version numbers but their hours and everything else is the same. Confirmed with the data owner that there are duplicates & I should use the higher version #. Sometimes your better off starting simple with an approach to solve an issue rather than making it more complex. I did the opposite. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank . . . You might want to ask a new question, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hey Gordon- Based on my first table, I created a second table table (without the Version field) and summarize my department totals that way.  The numbers now look accurate.  But it took two tables to do it.  Was hoping to do everything in one table.  Is there a better approach?  Feels like I now may be under-thinking this.

Comment: @Frank . . . You don't need two tables.  You can just use `row_number()`.  However, it would be simpler to show the query after seeing sample data.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, break something like this down in to the smallest possible pieces.

First run the following and make sure this total adds up correctly:

```
Select t1a.[Department_No], sum(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), ISNULL(NULLIF([Paid Hours], ''), '0'))) as Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department
from [STD].[Payroll] t1a 
group by t1a.[Department_No]
```

This is the first to check to make sure you don't have any duplicate entries.
I would try a left outer join. Not sure the SQL is perfect, but should be easy to fix if not. Also Make sure Department_No is not a float.

```
select 
 [Department_No] 
,[Department_Description]
,[JOB_CODE]
,[JOB_CODE_DESC]
,[Paid Hours]
,[Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department]
from [STD].[Payroll] PAL
left outer join ( Select Department_No, sum(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), ISNULL(NULLIF([Paid Hours], ''), '0'))) as Total_Paid_Hours_by_Department
  from [STD].[Payroll] 
  group by [Department_No]
) TIA on t1a.[Department_No] = PAL.[Department_No]
```